# Edit HTML Table Data cell using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table, and each cell of the table will have two data attributes. What I'm trying to do is set a button to switch the value being shown in the table between those two attributes.

```
<table class="table1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-original="A" data-new="B"> A </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm able to set new text and get attributes outside the table, but whenever I try to within the table I keep receiving an error:

> 'Uncaught -> TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

I've been receiving this error for a number of commands `$('td').text()`, `.val()`, `.attr('td')`, `.getAttribute()`. 
Am I missing a plugin or something for getting and setting values from tables?

ANSWER: I figured out the reason, I was an idiot and didn't mention that there would be numerous TD elements with repeating tags. I eventually used Underscore.js's each method to iterate through them and parts of the below answer to swap the values.

Comment: Can you provide us the JS code..??

Comment: There is no JS code at the moment. I've been trying to get something to work properly in the Chrome console first.

Comment: have you tried using HTML function of JQuery like; $('td').html()

Comment: for attribute, you can use $('td').attr('attribute-name')

Comment: Sorry, I have tried both of those as well. I'll add them to the list.

Comment: are you able to access table at all?

Comment: can you tell us what do you mean by "within the table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04prb14g/):

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("td").text($.trim($("td").text()) == $("td").data("original") 
      ? $("td").data("new") : $("td").data("original"));
});
```

to switch between the `data-original` and `data-new` values by checking the current text in the td and using a ternary operator. 
By using `trim()` for the initial text issues in case of whitespace are taken care of (as I just noticed that you have whitespace in your example td).

Just in case the button isn't already in the DOM when the page is initially loaded, you have to adjust the `on()` to delegate the click event from a static parent element to the button, e.g. like this: `$(document).on("click", "button", function () { ...`
Instead of `$(document)` every other static parent element can be used.

And as you mentioned that the table will have multiple tds with data-attributes, I've just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp1rq4pt/) to take care of that:

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
   $("td").each(function () {
    $(this).text($.trim($(this).text()) == $(this).data("original") ?   
             $(this).data("new") : $(this).data("original"));
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code looks very similar to what I was trying to do, so there is probably some other reason I'm hitting this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `.text()` didn't work for you.

To set text inside `td` elements, you use `.text()`. To get the data inside `data-current` or `data-new`, jQuery has a handy function `.data(tag)`, for example `$(sel).data('current')`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukdaem63/) displaying usage of this on your problem.

Comment: I've tried pasting in the exact information on my end into your fiddle and it seems to work. So it has to be some other issue on my end. This helped, now I know its not a jQuery issue. Thanks